# intrinsic lock of an object on Linux JVM

Tags: java, jvm, posix-api

I learnt that:"Every object has an intrinsic lock associated with it."

I also learnt that on linux, JVM internally uses POSIX api's for multi-threading feature.

What is the name of the POSIX api that JVM uses to provide(create) an intrinsic lock for each object instance of a class?

Comment: Why? Do you want to know how you would do this in a non-JVM language/runtime? Simple curiosity? Knowledge of intent would be useful to direct an answer.

Comment: The reason I ask "why" is that the JVM's implementation is much, **much** more complex than something built for most other purposes would need to be. It is _not_ a thin wrapper around POSIX calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The locks the JVM use to implement `synchronized` are not operating system locks, but is implemented internally in the JVM.

This is for speed reasons as well as they lock something different.  The operating system has no special understanding of Java objects (as opposed to files, memory and so on) so the JVM has its own locking mechanism specially designed for this.

A lot of effort has gone into making this very fast.

Comment: i learnt that mutex(pthread_mutex_t) is implemented using atomic machine-language operations(performed on memory locations visible to all threads) and requires system calls only in case of lock contentions. so i was wondering, what jvm is doing when  we say synchronized to acquire the intrinsic lock of instance of a class.

Comment: i see the same purpose of Object.wait()/Object.notify() in java where notification procedure is used, because pthread_cond_wait() pthread_cond_signal() also runs on same notification idea.

Comment: The actual implementation is up to the JVM designers and has changed over time in the oracle JVM, as faster methods were found.  You can look at the hotspot sources in openjdk to see how it is done.  A simpler set of sources may be jamvm which is a very small but complete JVM